# C# Running 3 Semi-Dependent Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I have three functions I wish to call - void DoJob1() void DoJob2() and Cleanup().
DoJob2() should only run if DoJob() succeeds.  Cleanup should always be called.

I have been trying to get this working using the following:

```
Task theTask = new Task( () => DoJob1(), CancelTokenSource.Token );
theTask.ContinueWith( currTask => DoJob2(), 
  TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | 
  TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent );
theTask.ContinueWith( currTask => Cleanup() );
```

DoJob2 correctly runs after DoJob1, but Cleanup runs at the same time as this.  I can see why but cant see any easy way to stop this and make it correctly always run after both even if either fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DoJob2 correctly runs after DoJob1, but Cleanup runs at the same time as this.

That's because you're telling it to continue as soon as `theTask` (i.e. running DoJob1) succeeds. You can change `theTask` to point to the completion of `DoJob2`.

```
Task theTask = new Task( () => DoJob1(), CancelTokenSource.Token );
theTask = theTask.ContinueWith( currTask => DoJob2(), 
  TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | 
  TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent );
theTask.ContinueWith( currTask => Cleanup() );
```

Or you can use inline syntax:

```
Task theTask = new Task( () => DoJob1(), CancelTokenSource.Token ) 
    .ContinueWith( currTask => DoJob2(), 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | 
        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent )
    .ContinueWith( currTask => Cleanup() );
```

If possible, you might also consider using `async/await` syntax:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoJob1());
    await Task.Run(() => DoJob2());
}
finally
{
    await Task.Run(() => CleanUp());
}
```

Of course, from the example you've given, it's hard to understand why you're using `Task`s at all, since you don't appear to have any async code. Maybe you can just simplify things:

```
try
{
    DoJob1();
    DoJob2();
}
finally
{
    CleanUp();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll give it a go. The real code does have async code I simplified it down to basics for an easy to describe q.